# Array of String to Array of Struct in Scala + Spark

Tags: scala, nested, apache-spark-sql

I am currently using Spark and Scala 2.11.8

I have the following schema:

```
root
|-- partnumber: string (nullable = true)
|-- brandlabel: string (nullable = true)
|-- availabledate: string (nullable = true)
|-- descriptions: array (nullable = true)
|-- |--   element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I am trying to use UDF to convert it to the following:

```
root
|-- partnumber: string (nullable = true)
|-- brandlabel: string (nullable = true)
|-- availabledate: string (nullable = true)
|-- description: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- cost: int(nullable = true)
```

So source data looks like this:

```
[WrappedArray(a abc 100,b abc 300)]
[WrappedArray(c abc 400)]
```

I need to use " " (space) as a delimiter, but don't know how to do this in scala.

```
def convert(product: Seq[String]): Seq[Row] = {
    ??/
}
```

I am fairly new in Scala, so can someone guide me how to construct this type of function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if I understand your problem right, but [map](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#map) could be your friend.

```
case class Row(a: String, b: String, c: Int)
val value = List(List("a", "abc", 123), List("b", "bcd", 321))

value map {
    case List(a: String, b: String, c: Int) => Row(a,b,c);
}
```

if you have to parse it first:

```
val value2 = List("a b 123", "c d 345")
value2 map {
    case s => { 
        val split = s.toString.split(" ")
        Row(split(0), split(1), split(2).toInt)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I try to implement your suggestion, but it is saying that "cannot resolve symbol split" Should I use different method?

Comment: [String.split](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#split(separator:Char):Array[String]) is a method for strings. I dont know what type is in your wrapped arrays. Perhaps you have to call toString on each value to have a string. 

val split = s.toString.split(" ")

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve this problem with your help.